# Apex incorporating an if statement into a block of text

Tags: string, if-statement, apex

I am converting a flow to Apex and within the Flow I have a formula field that creates a string. Within that formula I have conditional code to vary the wording. But I am not sure how to do that within Apex.

Flow Code:

```
`'Introduction line of text. ' + BR() + BR() + IF({varTotal} > 1, "Set Account: " ,"Customer Account: ") + 'Name'`
```

So if varTotal is more than 1 then the line would be

> Introduction line of text. **CS Account:** Name

If varTotal is = 1 then the text would be

> Introduction line of text. **Customer Account:** Name

When I try do that in Apex:

```
    String textBlock= 'Introduction line of text.<br/><br/>' 
    + totalSelected > 1 ?  'CS Account: ' : 'Customer Account: ' 
    + 'Name<br/><br/>'
```

It gives me an error and won't let me save it.

Is there an easy way to do what I want or do I have to create a variable to set outside of building the if statement and then just use that variable in the text block? There are several places where I have to do this so it is much easier if I can do it all in the text block.

Answer (score 0):

ok I found an example of how I should be doing this. Instead of Just trying to add all these lines to the text block I can build the text block line by line using the += operator. So my example should be:

```
String textBlock = 'Introduction line of text.<br/><br/>';
textBlock += totalSelected > 1 ?  'CS Account: ' : 'Customer Account: ';
textBlock += 'Name<br/><br/>';
```